# Loopback How query in "hasManyThrough" relation in base to the related models?

Tags: filter, where-clause, has-many-through, loopbackjs, relation

Assuming the standard example of physicians and patiens used by StrongLoop (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations):

common/models/physician.json

```
{
  "name": "Physician",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "patients": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Patient",
      "foreignKey": "patientId",
      "through": "Appointment"
    },
```

common/models/patient.json

```
{  
  "name": "Patient",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "physicans": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Physician",
      "foreignKey": "physicianId",
      "through": "Appointment"
    },
```

common/models/appointment.json

```
{  
  "name": "Appointment",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "appointmentDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "physician": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Physician",
      "foreignKey": "physicianId"
    },
    "patient": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Patient",
      "foreignKey": "patientId"
    },
```

Lets supouse than One Physician can have 0,1,2 or more Patients.
This way:

```
PhysicianId | PatientId
1----------------1
1----------------2
2----------------3
2----------------4
3----------------3
3----------------5
```

How can I get all the Physicians than have the same Patient??

**By example:**

Get all the Physicians than have the Patients with patientId 3??

*In this case the result must be: PhysicianId 2 and 3.*

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /patients/{id}/physicians
```

See [methods added to the model](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations#HasManyThroughrelations-Methodsaddedtothemodel).